# what are the drawbacks of using this query to get a random row fast

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been I looking for a way to get a random row with a where clause. I've seen a lot of posts on stackoverflow and they all have some drawback or are too complicated and ugly.

But I found this query and it looks pretty simple and smart

Can you see any major flaws with it scaling?

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, rand_col) VALUES(1,2,RAND());
```

Then selection of the random row becomes quite trivial task:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE rand_col>RAND() LIMIT 1
```

This algorithm allows removal of the records without the extra steps of key column recalculation.

Appologies about the formatting.I am using a mobile phone

Comment: Does your table have a surrogate primary key (such as an autoincrement number)?

Comment: Is it safe to assume rand_col would be indexed (since you mention speed as a requirement)? I guess I have trouble understanding why you wouldn't use the same query against an auto-incrementing column, scaling RAND() to the limits of the table values.

Comment: @mattball there is a primary key but it is not auto incremented with gaps

Answer (score 1):

I see the following drawbacks:

1. With no ordering, it will default to insertion order, so records that have been inserted early have a higher chance of being returned. I.e. it's not very random.
2. There will be cases where you get no result and have to execute the query repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

The drawbacks are several as listed, a good solution is:

Find the number of rows in the table, pick a random number in there and select the row.

```
     $row = SELECT table_rows*rand() FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name='foo'
     SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT $row,1
```

Comment: Fixed, sorry meant tables table.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra column. It's just a waste of space and code to maintain it. Just use

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Isn't it a lit of work creating these random rows every time everytime

Comment: No, it's just a call to a fast C library function.

Comment: @code578841441 You are correct, this has to assign every row a random value before it can return a single result.  It will be very slow for big tables.

Comment: @Austin Very slow compared to what? Slower than *reading* a random number from a column on the disk?

Comment: @EJP Actually I think this might depend on what storage engine you are using.  For InnoDB, MySQL doesn't know how many rows there are in the first place, so it has to walk over the whole index (which is on disk) to assign random values.  For MyISAM, `ORDER BY rand()` might be fast, but only if there is no where clause to filter results.  In that case, it will still have to walk the whole table to find all the results that match that where clause.

Comment: @Austin `SELECT *` has to walk the whole table anyway if there's a random column. This technique saves that disk space and whatever I/O is associated with it. It can't be slower than what he's doing now.

Comment: @EJP Not if there is an index on `rand_col`; in that case it will only have to make a few reads to walk the index to the particular value that `rand()` generates in the select query, and the one final read to read the row that gets found.  Of course OP never said if he is indexing `rand_col`, but it would be silly not to in this case.

Comment: Here's the results of my benchmark, which had two tables named `m` for MyISAM and `i` for InnoDB that are set up with three int columns each, one of which is a random number and is indexed.  Each table has 10000 rows.  Times are in seconds averaged over 1000 trials:
`0.002904: "SELECT * FROM m ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"
0.000088: "SELECT * FROM m WHERE rand_col > RAND() ORDER BY rand_col LIMIT 1"
0.004313: "SELECT * FROM i ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"
0.000108: "SELECT * FROM i WHERE rand_col > RAND() ORDER BY rand_col LIMIT 1"`

Comment: Yes but your rand_col>RAND idea is a range type comparison and MySQL will no longer be able to use any part of the index that comes after it. It might work well in certain instances and not others.